# How to sign build with .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

My Folder View

[image]

I am looking for the signing tab in Property, but can not find it.
The property is empty.

[image]

My Release

[image]

How to sign Release?

Comment: I think you want to right-click the project and select "Properties"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to right-click the project in Solution Explorer:

[image]

From here you'll see the Signing tab:

[image]

Which has the options to sign your assembly:

[image]